# get the unid of selected documents and save to scoped variable

Tags: xpages

I've a viewPanel1 with checkboxes. By clicking on a button I would like to save the univ id's (comma seperated) of the selected items to a scoped variable. I tried this :

`var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1"); 
    var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
    for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length;i++){
    var docId=docIDArray[i];
    sessionScope.put("test",+docId);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
var unidArray = new Array();
for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
   var unid=database.getDocumentByID(docIDArray[i]).getUniversalID();
   unidArray.push(unid);
}
sessionScope.put("test", @Implode(unidArray, ","));
```

This will probably do it.

Comment: Keep in mind this can be a performance drain if the user has selected a lot of documents..

Comment: That is a very true statement!

Comment: This seems to give me only the last selected unid. (user will in this case only select 1 or 2 documents so performance should be ok)

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistyped the last line, it should include @Implode(unidArray), I have edited my code up above.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget that scoped variables can hold an array, so you don't really need to box/unbox the array:

sessionScope.put("SelectedIds", getComponent("viewPanel1").getSelectedIds());

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following

```
var vPanel = getComponent("viewPanel");
docIdArray = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
sessionScope.put("SelectedIds",@Implode(docIdArray,","));
```

Comment: This gives me the id's , but how to get the unid's of the selected documents ? (i've put them in the column unid of the view)