# viewpanel selections being unselected on dialog box show

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an extension pages dialog box on the same page as a viewpanel that has check boxes enabled.  If I check some check boxes then show  the dialog box, the selections in the view panel become unselected.  Is anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and it looks like we're trying to do the same thing.  I plan to add the selected IDs to a sessionScope, update their values, then remove the sessionScope.

I found this one, so I'll update here to see if it works:  [get the unid of selected documents and save to scoped variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054820/get-the-unid-of-selected-documents-and-save-to-scoped-variable)

UPDATE:

I got it to work by setting a sessionScope variable for the selected IDs, as in the above example:

sessionScope.put("SelectedIds", getComponent("viewPanel1").getSelectedIds());

In the SSJS script, I changed the code to read the sessionScope array instead of the viewPanel's selections.
   Fortunately, the IDs are very small (3 characters), so if there are a lot of documents, it should be ok.

Good luck!

Comment: Yep.  Great minds think alike.  I did pretty much the same  thing to resolve the issue.  I am just glad to see I am not the only one having the issue.   Do the opentf folks hang out here or should I go there to report this issue?

Comment: I know a few OpenNTF people who check here, but since we're talking about a possible bug in the Extension Library dialog, then I added the "extlib" tag so they can find it easier.