# Get selected documents from a view and save as separate document

Tags: xpages

I am trying to get selected documents from a view and save as separate documents

Here is the design of the xpage

A combo box on the top, a view with check box (this view is used for selection), a button for save the selection values from the view and the combo box. Also there will another view which will display the saved values.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054820/get-the-unid-of-selected-documents-and-save-to-scoped-variable), I can get the unid of selected documents and save to view scope variable. The add button can save the selected value from the combo box and the view and show the result in another view.

However, if I choose more than one value in the view and click save, it saves all values in one document. So I try to use for loop to loop through the selected values in view and save, it still saves one value only in one document.

```
   <xp:table id="table1a">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td id="table1">
            <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1"
                dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" style="width:250.0px"
                value="#{document1.Category}">
                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems3">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var SetFirstValueBlank = @Text("");
                    return SetFirstValueBlank;
                }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems4">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(), "CategoryListView", 1));}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="table1a">
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:comboBox>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:viewPanel rows="10" id="viewPanel1" var="rowData">
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                        viewName="hListView">
                    </xp:dominoView>
                </xp:this.data>
                <xp:viewColumn columnName="ItemName"
                    id="viewColumn1" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)"
                    showCheckbox="true">
                    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Item Name"
                        id="viewColumnHeader1" rendered="false">
                    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                </xp:viewColumn>
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                        layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="footerPager" id="pager2">
                    </xp:pager>
                </xp:this.facets>
            </xp:viewPanel>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:button value="Add" id="button1"
                style="height:35.0px">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var Category = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();
                    var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");
                    var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
                    var unidArray = new Array();
                    for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
                   var unid=database.getDocumentByID(docIDArray[i]).getUniversalID();
                      unidArray.push(unid);
                    }
                    viewScope.put("unidArray", @Implode(unidArray, ","));
                for(var i=0; i< unidArray.length;i++ )
                {
                    document1.replaceItemValue("ItemName", unidArray[i]);
                    document1.save();
                }
        }]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:viewPanel rows="6" id="viewPanel2">                     
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="CategoryItemView">
                            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var value = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();
                    if(value =="" || value == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }}]]></xp:this.rendered><xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn4" columnName="Category" rendered="false">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader4" value="Category">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn3" columnName="$10">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader3" value="Category">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ItemName" id="viewColumn2">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Item" id="viewColumnHeader2">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="footerPager" id="pager3">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets></xp:viewPanel><xp:br></xp:br></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
```

Would someone let me know how to save multiple values in separate documents please? Thank you.

(edit: some of previous content are removed)

I think I will focus on how to save multiple value as separate documents first because this part is quite important in the program, once I can save as separate documents, there will another function that needs the result to process.

I review the code, I think I will still use for loop but unfortunately, it still saves one document only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the document1 object is bound to a  on the XPage, which is only created when the XPage is opened. To cause your button to create multiple documents, the for loop needs to modified :

```
var oneOfMany : NotesXspDocument;
for(var i=0; i< unidArray.length;i++ )
{
  oneOfMany = database.createDocument();
  oneOfMany.replaceItemValue( "Category",  document1.getItemValue("Category" ) );
  oneOfMany.replaceItemValue("ItemName", unidArray[i]);
  oneOfMany.replaceItemValue("form", "MyFormName" );
  oneOfMany.save();
}
```

Because it no longer uses document1, this loop will need to populate the other items you need such as the form, for example **MyFormName** as in the example.

Comment: Thanks for me know to use `database.createDocument`, before I receive your answer, I don't know I can use this code in the for loop. So I can save  multiple value as separate documents now. Thank you very much.

Comment: But one thing I notice that if I use `database.createDocument()`, the `Run form validation` --> choose `On document save` will not work. Even I write an agent using formula and then use `database.getAgent("myAgent").run()`, it does not work.

Comment: The reason I need to use those methods because there are some computed fields form, when I save the document, those computed fields will update (it will be used in another function). However, in a new xpage that use simple data binding, (datasource is document1), the `Run form validation` --> `choose On document save`  and `database.getAgent("myAgent").run()` both work properly. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Sure, add  `oneOfMany.computeWithForm( false, false);  ` just before the save. This is the same as the _Run form validation_ option. Check the help for more information about the _computeWithForm_ method and how it can be used. Just a word of caution however, it can be a time intensitve operation especially over many documents and a complex form, so consider adding the additional fields manually.

Comment: Hello, I know this post has posted for a while. thanks your comment, I can save multiple documents separately. May I ask a question base on this post please. Is it possible to have data binding in the view?

Comment: The reason is if I need to edit the document, in the edit page, is it possible to make the view "remembers" the saved selection and put a "tick" in the checkbox?. So far as I know, suppose there a edit box or a combo box, if I use data binding to bind to a field and save it, the a edit box or a combo box can show the saved value when edit.

Comment: So I would like to know can the "similar approach" applies to the view? I search on the Internet and not much information about it. Do you have any advice on this issue? Thank you